# Expected substring: "Unknown database 'hi0'" Received function did not throw

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a peice of code that i know very well that it will throw an error because the database does not exists name `hi0`. Here is how i'm handling my `test``

```
test("Testing connection using MySQL", () => {
  expect(() =>
    (async () => {
      const conn = await getConnection({
        config: {
          database: "hi0",
          host: "127.0.0.1",
          port: 3306,
          password: "root",
          user: "root",
        },
        dialect: "mysql",
      });
      const loom = new Dataloom({
        conn,
        entities: [User],
        logger: "console",
      });
      await loom.synchronize({ drop: false });
    })()
  ).toThrow(Error);
});
```

To my surprise here is the error that i'm getting.

```bash
  Expected substring: "Unknown database 'hi0'"

  Received function did not throw
```

What must be possibly the issue here?